# passing sliced view of numpy array to cython - where is the copy happening?

Tags: python, cython

In the following code I am slicing an array X, thereby creating a view on X, named `X_cut`. Then I use a cython memory view on the slice and pass it as 1d array to a c function that accesses the memory linearly.

Can I be sure that the pointer passed to the C code is actually referring to a 6x6 linearised matrix?

If so where is the copy operation happening? Is it in `X_cut.ravel()`?

```
%%cython

import numpy as np

cdef extern from "/some/path/to/get_5_5.c":
    long get5_5(long* arr, int M, int N)

M = 6
N = 8

X = np.arange(M*N).reshape(M, N)

N_cut = 6
X_cut = X[:, :N_cut]

cdef long[::1] arr = X_cut.ravel()

print(get5_5(&arr[0], M, N_cut))
```

/some/path/to/get_5_5.c

```
long get5_5(long* arr, int M, int N) {
  return arr[5*N + 5];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cython's typed memory views use [Buffer-Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html) to get access to the data, that means they have nothing to do with copying of the data.

Theoretically, an exporter could decide to copy the data when exposing it via Buffer-Protocol. However, usually Buffer-Protocol is used in order to avoid memory-copying, so copying is not the normal case. That means, you cannot be 100% sure, that no copying is happening when binding a typed memory view to an object exporting the buffer - you have to know the implementation of the exporter, but the cases of copying are really rare. And this is not what happening here.

The copying must happen, when `X_cut.ravel()` is called - the [resulting memory must be contiguous](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html#numpy-ravel), but the underlying memory in `X_cut` isn't (see `X_cut.flags`), because it still shares memory with `X` and cutting off the last elements per row results in "holes" in memory.

Here are the memory layouts (for simplicity M=2, N=3, N_cut=2):

```
  X:               X00,X01,X02,X10,X11,X12
  X_cut:           X00,X01,...,X10,X11        # ... - hole in memory, no copying
  X_cut.ravel():   X00,X01,X10,X11            # memory contiguous, copying needed
```

---

Where does it leave you? You either have to accept the copying of the memory or extend the interface of `get5_5`, so you can also pass non-contiguous memory layouts - not unsimilar to the Buffer-Protocol.

For example to pass `X_cut` without copying you will need to specify not (only) the shape, but also the strides along the dimensions, i.e.

```
#only stride along the the first dimension is needed:
cdef long get5_5(long* arr, int stride_row, int stride_col):
     return arr[stride_row*5+5]
```

The question is, how to get the pointer `long* arr` from `X_cut` without copying.

One possibility is to use 2D-memory view I would choose this option):

```
cdef long[:,::1] arr = X_cut
get5_5(&arr[0][0], M, N) # and not M, N_cut
```

another would be to use `np.reshape(-1)`, which creates a new 1-dimensional-view and doesn't **always** copy the data (unlike `np.ravel()`):

```
cdef long[::1] arr = X.reshape(-1) # X_cut.reshape(-1) would copy the data!
get5_5(&arr[0], M, N)  # and not M, N_cut
```

Comment: This then raises a question - if the buffer protocol _could_ copy, should it be used to modify arrays in place? (In practice it's fine for most real cases, of course). I'd think that a well-behaved buffer should give you access to the actual memory of an object and not a copy, although it might be acceptable to change how an object stores it's data before returning the buffer if you knew there were no other references to that data.

Comment: @DavidW I would be stuggling to name any widely used example where this happens, but it is technically possible - so I just trying to convey one cannot be 100% sure.